# Запуск консольного приложения C# на macOS

Tags: c#, консоль, macos

Хочу запустить консольное приложение C# на macOS, отрабатывает, но не предлагается пользователю ввести что-то с клавиатуры, плюс в терминале знаки вопроса. Честно говоря, ничего не нашел в Google, могли бы помочь?

```
Building Lesson01 (Debug)
Build started 6/11/2023 12:19:15 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/ov/CS/source/Lesson01.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target GenerateBindingRedirects:
    No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Roslyn/csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/mscorlib.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Core.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Data.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Xml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.8-api/System.Xml.Linq.dll /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/Lesson01.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:7.3 Program.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs "obj/Debug/.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
    CompilerServer: server - server processed compilation - 4e2bda80-39d7-4223-9ef5-3ca907afac98
Target _CopyAppConfigFile:
  Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Copying file from "/Users/ov/CS/source/Lesson01/obj/Debug/Lesson01.exe" to "/Users/CS/source/gb/charp1/Lesson01/Lesson01/bin/Debug/Lesson01.exe".
    Lesson01 -> /Users/CS/source/Lesson01/bin/Debug/Lesson01.exe
    Copying file from "/Users/ov/Desktop/source/Lesson01/obj/Debug/Lesson01.pdb" to "/Users/ov/Desktop/2/CS/source/Lesson01/bin/Debug/Lesson01.pdb".
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:05.86
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
Build successful.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте нормальное Visual Studio 2022. А так, проблема в кодировке. Попробуйте поменять `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`, быть может ещё шрифт придётся поменять. Ещё не используйте .NET Framework 4.x, используйте .NET 6 или новее.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Извините, а что значит "нормальное VS 2022", у меня VS for Mac последняя. Проблем с шрифтом ушла, но почему-то пользователю не возвращается окошко ввода с консоли своих данных. Добавил два скриншота выше.